# Search for a String, and retrieve all lines following it until another specific pattern

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk, grep

From a unix script, I want to search a text file for a string and then return all the lines following the pattern up until a line that contains the word "Failed".

For example,

```
Test Case Name "Blah"
Error 1
Error 2
Error 3
Failed
Test Case Name "Foo"
Pass
Test Case Name "Red"
Pass
```

In the above, I want to search for "Blah", and then return:

```
Error 1
Error 2
Error 3
```

Up until the line "Failed".  There can be any number of "Error" lines between "Blah" and "Failed".

Any solutions using sed, awk, etc. are acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you not including the line `Failed` from output? What if the one to be searched has `Pass` instead?

Comment: Ideally I'd like without "Failed", but I can work around it.  If one has "Pass", it will be just the one line (nothing else), but I already have that taken care of

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the awk version:

```
$ awk '/Failed/{p=0}p;/Blah/{p=1}' file
Error 1
Error 2
Error 3
```

And if you don't mind printing the boundary lines, you can do

```
awk '/Blah/,/Failed/' file
```

---

Some explanations how this works: an awk script is essentially a series of blocks with the structure `filter{actions}`, where the filter defines for which input records, the actions will be applied.

So the first block `/Failed/{p=0}` says that if we find a record that contains the regular expression `Failed`, we set the variable `p` to zero.

The second block `p;` uses the default action, which is to print the current record. So for each record that is read, the script checks the value of the `p` variable, and prints the record if `p` has a non-zero value (which is equivalent to the true condition).

The third block `/Blah/{p=1}` says that if we find a record that contains the regular expression `Blah`, to set the variable `p` to one.

So if we put them all together, the script starts reading all input lines without printing them (since the initial value of `p` is zero). After a record containing `Blah` is found, the following records are printed until a record containing `Failed` is found. Since the blocks are examined for each record in the order that they appear, the order of the three blocks will determine what happens to the boundary records. For example, if the boundary lines were to be printed we could write the script as `awk '/Blah/{p=1}p;/Failed/{p=0}' file`.

The second command `awk '/Blah/,/Failed/' file` uses a range construct (the comma). The operation of the range construct is documented nicely here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html

Comment: Nice simple variation. Also perhaps change `/Blah/` to `/^Test Case Name "Blah"/`, and `/Failed/` to `/^Failed/` to become more specific but that's just an option. Perhaps it's enough already.

Comment: Hi user000001 ! Would have been great if you could have explained what exactly each of the  parameters meant?

Comment: @AnandBuilders: I made an edit to explain how it works. Let me know if anything is still unclear

Comment: Thanks user000001 . It works fine. One more concern i have is that ti am using shell variable. So when i replace blah with my shell variable, it fails. Any help for that as i being a novice in shell?

Comment: @AnandBuilders: Try like this `awk -v start="$var1" -v end="$var2" '$0 ~ end {p=0} p; $0 ~ start{p=1}' file` for a regex match or `awk -v start="$var1" -v end="$var2" '$0 == end {p=0} p; $0 == start{p=1}' file` for a literal match.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/Blah/,/Failed/{//!p}' file
```